# Why there is a dot before file name parameter of fs.readFile (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js

Following a tutorial on Node.js' URL module (https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_url.asp), I notice that the file name gets a starting dot before it become a parameter of fs.readFile (line 7). The server returns 404 without the dot, but I can't grasp the reason. Can you help, please?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var filename = "." + q.pathname; // here it gets the DOT
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            return res.end("404 Not Found");
        }  
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the article states, `q.pathname` is `/default.htm`:

```
var adr = 'http://localhost:8080/default.htm?year=2017&month=february';
var q = url.parse(adr, true);

console.log(q.host); //returns 'localhost:8080'
console.log(q.pathname); //returns '/default.htm'
```

`/default.htm` is absolute file path, `fs.readFile` would read be it from root directory, while `./default.htm` is relative path, `fs.readFile` reads it from current working directory.

It should be mentioned that string concatenation is not a safe way to create file paths, this preferably should be done with `path.join`:

```
var path = require('path');
...
var filename = path.join(".", q.pathname); // === 'default.htm'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the leading dot is that the logic of that example is to open a local file.
`q.pathname` will return something like `/`..., so adding a `.` in front of it, you'll get something like `./`..., which identifies a file in the same directory where the node.js program is run.